# Pyspark: Remove UTF null character from pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, utf-8, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe similar to the following:

```
df = sql_context.createDataFrame([
  Row(a=3, b=[4,5,6],c=[10,11,12], d='bar', e='utf friendly'),
  Row(a=2, b=[1,2,3],c=[7,8,9], d='foo', e=u'ab\u0000the')
  ])
```

Where one of the values for column `e` contains the UTF null character `\u0000`. If I try to load this `df` into a postgresql database, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

which makes sense. How can I efficiently remove the null character from the pyspark dataframe before loading the data into postgres?

I have tried using some of the `pyspark.sql.functions` to clean the data first without success. `encode`, `decode`, and `regex_replace` did not work:

```
df.select(regexp_replace(col('e'), u'\u0000', ''))
df.select(encode(col('e'), 'UTF-8'))
df.select(decode(col('e'), 'UTF-8'))
```

Ideally, I would like to clean the entire dataframe without specifying exactly which columns or what the violating character is, since I don't necessarily know this information ahead of time.

I am using a postgres 9.4.9 database with `UTF8` encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah wait - I think I have it. If I do something like this, it seems to work:

```
null = u'\u0000'
new_df = df.withColumn('e', regexp_replace(df['e'], null, ''))
```

And then mapping to all string columns:

```
string_columns = ['d','e']
new_df = df.select(
  *(regexp_replace(col(c), null, '').alias(c) if c in string_columns else c for
    c in df.columns)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.fillna()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) to replace null values.

> Replace null values, alias for na.fill(). DataFrame.fillna() and
> DataFrameNaFunctions.fill() are aliases of each other.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - *value* – int, long, float, string, or dict. Value to
>   replace null values with. If the value is a dict, then subset is
>   ignored and value must be a mapping from column name (string) to
>   replacement value. The replacement value must be an int, long, float,
>   or string.
> - *subset* – optional list of column names to consider. Columns
>   specified in subset that do not have matching data type are ignored.
>   For example, if value is a string, and subset contains a non-string
>   column, then the non-string column is simply ignored.

Comment: I don't think that works here, because the problem cell isn't actually null - it contains the UTF null character \u0000. If I run `df.fillna()` on my example df, it looks like it returns the same dataframe, since none of the cells are actually null. If I try to load the resulting df into a postgres table, I still get the same error message.