# Replace null character in a string in Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I need to replace a null character in a spark sql string.

I can't find an equivalent of COLLATE in spark sql.

Can you help?

Comment: Do you mean `coalesce`?

Comment: show some sample data

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to replace every NULL character in a string you can use `regexp_replace`. Depending on the encoding and programming language you use the NULL character can be different: `\000`, `\x00`, `\z`, or `\u0000`. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)]

```py
null_character = u'\u0000'
replacement = ' '
df = df.withColumn('e', F.regexp_replace(F.col('columnX'), null_character, replacement))
```

Related response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152572/14338716